# Regex for string validation (with char tags)

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex to validate string.

```
string test = "C:\Dic\<:Id:>.<:Dic:>testtest<:Location:>.Test.doc"
```

I made I regex to get all fields between "<:" and ":>".

```
  Regex.Matches(fileNameConfig, @"\<(.+?)\>")
                    .Cast<Match>()
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).ToList();
```

Now, I need to check that if are there any opened tags that have not  close tags and are there any nested tags.

```
string test = "C:\Dic\<:<:Id:>.<:Dic:>testtest<:Location:>.Test.doc"
string test = "<:C:\Dic\<:Id:>.<:Dic:>testtest<:Location:>.Test.doc:>"
```

Comment: Usually, [nesting is hard/impossible to do with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/107625), because the "language" does not support nested structures.

Comment: While .NET regex allows balanced constructs, it is rather unclear how to use them here. What are the requirements?

Comment: As I wrote I need to get substrings between "<:" and ":>" from string but before i need check that all tags all correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nesting can be tested by counting the opening and closing brackets.

At any position in the string, the number of opening brackets before this position must be greater or equal the number of closing brackets.

At the end of the string, the number of opening brackets must equal the number of closing brackets exactly.

```
public static bool IsBracketNestingValid(string input) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) {
        return true; // empty string is always nested correctly
    }

    const string openingBracket = "<:";
    const string closingBracket = ":>";
    if (input.Length < openingBracket.Length) {
        // perform this check if we expect that input strings 
        // must contain at least one bracket (e.g. "<" should be invalid)
        return false; 
    }

    int openingCount = 0;
    int closingCount = 0;
    for (int pos = 0; pos < input.Length-1; pos++) {

        string currentToken = string.Format("{0}{1}", input[pos], input[pos+1]);            

        if (currentToken == openingBracket) {
            openingCount++;
            // skip over this recognized token 
            // (so we do not count any ':' twice, e.g. "<:>" should be invalid)
            pos++; 
        }
        if (currentToken == closingBracket) {
            closingCount++;
            pos++; // skip over this recognized token
        }
        if (closingCount > openingCount) {
            return false; // found closing bracket before opening bracket
        }
    }

    return openingCount == closingCount;
}
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4DPJi)